# sql combine many rows into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I cant figure out how to do the following selection in sql:

Table:

```
id score1 score2 score3
0  null   null   3
0  1      null   3
1  null   2      null
```

select:

```
id score1 score2 score3
0  1      null   3
1  null   2      null
```

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate the values using `MAX`

```
SELECT ID, 
       MAX(score1) score1,
       MAX(score2) score2,
       MAX(score3) score3
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I think this is a clean solution. And it's working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is based on choosing the row that has more scores filled out than any other row for the same ID.  Keeping the "best" data, if you will.

```
select id, score1, score2, score3
from (
    select *,
       rn=row_number() over (partition by id
                             order by
                                case when score1 is not null then 1 else 0 end
                                +
                                case when score2 is not null then 1 else 0 end
                                +
                                case when score3 is not null then 1 else 0 end desc)
    from tbl
) x
where rn=1
```

e.g.

```
id score1 score2 score3
0  null   4      null
0  1      null   3         <<< keep
1  null   2      null
```

Of course, you may prefer John's answer which will make the row (0,1,4,3) for ID=0.